# Add default email variable in link URL

Tags: php, html, redirect

I want to add a variable Email address into the link (so email address dynamically fills when someone hit the link), which re-direct PHP. Email addresses are different based on person visited the link. So I am wondering, how can I in ordinary URL address add variable Email, which will then intervened and added to PHP re-direct?

This is the code, but not working...

```
<?PHP
$subid=$_GET[subid];
$email=$_GET[email];
?>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://xentrk.com/?a=41&c=308&s1={{ email|default:'null' }}<?PHP echo $subid;?>" />
</head>

<body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `echo $subid` in your URL:

Surely this should be `$email` ?

In which case this is the code:

```
<?php
$subid=$_GET['subid'];
$email=$_GET['email'];
?>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://xentrk.com/?a=41&c=308&s1={{ email|default:'null' }}<?php echo $email;?>" />
</head>

<body>
```